# link opening new window and refreshing current

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using the following PHP line to create a link in a table to a new window

```
echo "<a href=\"InterfaceInfo.php?FXOrder=" . $row['FXOrder'] . "&TA5k=" . $TA5k . "&EfmGroup=" . urlencode($row['EfmGroup']) . "&EfmLink=no\" onclick=\"window.open(this.href, 'mywin','left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=1')\"><center>1/" . $row['EfmGroup'] . "</center></a>";
```

This is working correctly for opening the new window. However, once the new window it loaded the current window with the link also opens the same link. What am I doing wrong with this?

Comment: `htmlentities()` is USELESS when you're building a URL. a URL is not html. You need `urlencode()` instead.

Comment: changed to urlencode, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the end of your link add `;return false;`. This will prevent an action on the current window:

`<a href=\"InterfaceInfo.php?FXOrder=" . $row['FXOrder'] . "&TA5k=" . $TA5k . "&EfmGroup=" . urlencode($row['EfmGroup']) . "&EfmLink=no\" onclick=\"window.open(this.href, 'mywin','left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=1');return false;\">`

Answer (score 1):

The browser will navigate to whatever is set in `href`-attribute. If you do not want any action use `href="javascript:void()"` or less "valid" `href="#"`.

Copy what you have currently in href to the `window.open()` instead of the `this.href`.

Comment: The window.open location is baed on the href, doing this will make neither work

Comment: Right, I was hoping that would be clear. I've updated my answer, to state this.

Comment: changed to `<a href=\"javascript:void()\" onclick=\"window.open( \"InterfaceInfo.php?FXOrder=" . $row['FXOrder'] . "&TA5k=" . $TA5k . "&EfmGroup=" . urlencode($row['EfmGroup']) . "&EfmLink=no\" , 'mywin','left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=1')\"><center>1/" . $row['EfmGroup'] . "</center></a>` and nothing is popping up now

Comment: That might be a browser issue. Almost all browsers block popups generated in this way.

Comment: is there a better way I should be using to send the link to a new window?

Comment: Well you could do it with href and `target="_blank"`

Comment: `this.href` is perfectly fine and useful for using the current href attribute in `window.open`. Copying the link makes for a lot longer code when this isn't needed.